# How to avoid web crawlers and bots to call your script?

Tags: javascript, web, bots, web-crawler, search-engine

My website is having a script tag which links to a script which helps me keep track of all the user activity in my web page. My web page has click events linked to that script's function.

I want web crawlers and bots to either not load that script or send me wrong data from the click events.

Also want to know if web crawlers and bots can call the script scr or call the click events in my page and send me wrong data from that page. Is this possible??

Thank you in advance.

I checked the whole internet and found nothing, stackoverflow community can help!! Please.

Comment: Bots wont usually simulate clicks, so your event listener won't be called.

Comment: Thank you so much for replying, but are you sure and is there any way I can justify this. like any link or how can I test this.

Comment: i don't think there is any links out there that can back that up, simply because there is too much bots/web crawlers/web scrappers out there, so there is no definitive answer. Bots usually don't simulate clicks because they don't have/need to